# Добавление файла PDF в Admin panel

Tags: php, mysql

Как правильно организовать добавление файла PDF в админ панели сайта? Где лучше хранить эти данные — в БД или папке ресурса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Храните файлы в файловой системе, а в БД храните ссылку на этот файл.
В БД записываете путь к файлу относительно имени вашего домена.
А сам файл добавляете на сервер (или куда вам нужно), например средствами php ( здесь указываете абсолютный путь к хранилищу сервера ):

```
move_uploaded_file
```

Соответственно, чтобы просмотреть файл, просто выводите на него ссылку, которую вы записали в вашу БД.

Вот пример добавления файла, как передаются файлы из html формы в массив $_FILES думаю знаете:

```
//Добавление файла
        $i=0;
        while($_FILES["myfile"]["name"][$i]!=NULL)
        {
        $upload_file=$_FILES["myfile"]["name"][$i];

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$i],"H://files");
        $folder="/files";
        $insert_path="INSERT INTO myfile 
        (FilePath,NameFile) 
        VALUES ('$folder','$upload_file')";
        mysqli_query($conn, $insert_path);
        $i++;
        }
```

Вот пример просмотра файла из БД:

```
$select_path="SELECT NameFile,FilePath FROM myfile ";
$var=mysqli_query($conn, $select_path);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($var))
{
$file_name=$row["NameFile"];
$file_path=$row["FilePath"];
echo '<br><label><a href="' .$file_path. '/'. $file_name. '">'. $file_name .'</a></label><p></p>';
}
```